# Can't import "GestureDetectorCompat" class

Tags: java, android, android-appcompat

I am trying to import `GestureDetectorCompat.class` into Android Studio but doesn't work.

I tried adding `import androidx.core.view.GestureDetectorCompat;` and `import   android.support.v4.view.GestureDetectorCompat;` above class definition of my activity but it shows `Cannot resolve symbol 'GestureDetectorCompat'` error.

Mousing over the `GestureDetectorCompat` in the code, I get options to add library to classpath, but clicking it does nothing and still cannot resolve the symbol.

I was trying to add it to ExoPlayer demo app PlayerActivity class.

```
private void initGesture()
{
    GestureDetectorCompat mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, this);
}
```

build.gradle (Module: app)

```
// Copyright (C) 2016 The Android Open Source Project
//
// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
// you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
// You may obtain a copy of the License at
//
//      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
//
// Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
// distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
// WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
// See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
// limitations under the License.
apply from: '../../constants.gradle'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion project.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        versionName project.ext.releaseVersion
        versionCode project.ext.releaseVersionCode
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion project.ext.targetSdkVersion
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles = [
                "proguard-rules.txt",
                getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
            ]
        }
        debug {
            jniDebuggable = true
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        // The demo app does not have translations.
        disable 'MissingTranslation'
    }

    flavorDimensions "extensions"

    productFlavors {
        noExtensions {
            dimension "extensions"
        }
        withExtensions {
            dimension "extensions"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:' + supportLibraryVersion
    implementation project(modulePrefix + 'library-core')
    implementation project(modulePrefix + 'library-dash')
    implementation project(modulePrefix + 'library-hls')
    implementation project(modulePrefix + 'library-smoothstreaming')
    implementation project(modulePrefix + 'library-ui')
    withExtensionsImplementation project(path: modulePrefix + 'extension-ffmpeg')
    withExtensionsImplementation project(path: modulePrefix + 'extension-flac')
    withExtensionsImplementation project(path: modulePrefix + 'extension-ima')
    withExtensionsImplementation project(path: modulePrefix + 'extension-opus')
    withExtensionsImplementation project(path: modulePrefix + 'extension-vp9')
    withExtensionsImplementation project(path: modulePrefix + 'extension-rtmp')
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.android.gms.strict-version-matcher-plugin'
```

I expected the class to be added and work normally but just comes up above problems.

Comment: Please add your gradle file.

Comment: @Tommy which gradle file?

Comment: The one in Module: app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:** [GestureDetectorCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/GestureDetectorCompat) belongs to `com.android.support:support-compat` dependency. You must add it into your dependencies in gradle file.

```
dependencies {
    // Your dependencies here.
    // ...

    // Add this line.
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
}
```

Then using in code.

```
import android.support.v4.view.GestureDetectorCompat;

private void initGesture() {
    GestureDetectorCompat mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, this);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I add the following answer for anyone who have this problem: (The previous one didn't work for me)

I had to replace the following import

`import android.support.v4.view.GestureDetectorCompat;`

with this:

`import androidx.core.view.GestureDetectorCompat;`

to use it.

I think the reason is that some subpackages from 'android.support.v4' are deprecated and we should use them from 'androidx'

[Source](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/issues/2839#issuecomment-511170816)

Answer (score 0):

With new version of Android v4 package has removed view from it. So to use `GestureDetactorCompat` with the above line of code.